# Restrict property covariance in generic argument

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

When I specify a generic argument of object type with some mandatory properties (e.g. here I have a function that requires the object to have `timestamp: string` to assign timestamp to it), typescript allows to use more specific attribute type as a generic argument - see example below.

Is there a way to restrict this? I think it violates inheritance principles, since object attributes are read/write, they should keep their type over inheritance and not allow covariant types.

```
function updateTimestamp<T extends {timestamp: string}>(x: T): T {
    return {...x, timestamp: new Date().toDateString()};
}

type Bar = {timestamp: 'not today'};

const b: Bar = updateTimestamp<Bar>({timestamp: 'not today'})
console.log(b); // {timestamp: (actual timestamp))}, should not match Bar
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCADgEwIZQKYBUYC22AzlBgSgDy6LYAeOYaxiA3rEaeSgFyKkAnGGADmAXwB8ACjp9cASjlsAsAChEiAdiggBSVgDojdADSIOJMhT5hsAd0QARLNinyDUOM5wBlKENE3MQBuNTE1NSgATxRsRAAhDAFEAF42Cy5rRAByMDgoczhMKOyQiNUIBFJEACM+ROS01EwcfE4rKgbpdkJLbj5c-MLi0vk1SrBiOAAbbANpuBEpGvlgxAB6dfTezN5EKQxoEAxp8x2O+XkxM2IACzgQabREPIKCLAhbhKS1IA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is (intentionally) [unsound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) this way: you are allowed to assign a value of type `A` to a variable of type `B` where `A extends B`, property values are considered to be covariant (if `A extends B` then for any common property key `K`, `A[K] extends B[K]`), and you are allowed to modify non `readonly` properties.  This permits unsound property writes. I don't know if there's canonical documentation about this; but GitHub issues like [microsoft/TypeScript#8474](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8474) and [microsoft/TypeScript#18770](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18770) talk about it.  It definitely violates inheritance principles, but to strictly enforce those principles would, according to the TypeScript team, make the language a lot more annoying to use.  So at some level this is unavoidable.

---

However, you could change your definition of `updateTimestamp()` to sidestep this problem.  One way to do it is to note that while `updateTimeStamp()` will accept a `T`, what it's returning is not necessarily a `T`.  Instead, it's a `{[K in keyof T]: K extends "timestamp" ? string: T[K]}`, or equivalently, `Omit<T, "timestamp"> & { timestamp: string }`:

```
function updateTimestamp<T extends { timestamp: string }>(
  x: T
): Omit<T, "timestamp"> & { timestamp: string } {
  return { ...x, timestamp: new Date().toDateString() };
}
```

The compiler can actually verify that the implementation adheres to the `Omit` version, so I've used that.  Now, if you call your `Bar` code, you'll get the error you expect:

```
const myBar: Bar = { timestamp: 'not today' };
const newBar = updateTimestamp(myBar);
/* const newBar: Pick<Bar, never> & {
    timestamp: string;
} */
const b: Bar = newBar; // error!
// -> ~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"not today"'.
```

while if you pass in an object whose `timestamp` is the wide `string` type, it will work:

```
let okay = { timestamp: "yesterday" }; 
/* let okay: {
    timestamp: string;
} */
okay = updateTimestamp(okay); // okay
```

There are other possible ways to change `updateTimestamp()` to express your intent.  Perhaps you actually want to prohibit accepting a `T` whose `timestamp` property is narrower than `string`.  This is harder to express but possible:

```
function updateTimestamp<T extends {
  timestamp: string & (string extends T["timestamp"] ? unknown : never)
}>(
  x: T
): T {
  return { ...x, timestamp: new Date().toDateString() };
}
```

And then you get this behavior:

```
const newBar = updateTimestamp(myBar); // error!
// --------------------------> ~~~~~
// Type '"not today"' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)

okay = updateTimestamp(okay); // okay
```

---

Luckily you are returning a new value and not modifying an existing value. This means the output of `updateTimestamp()` is essentially independent of its input, and so you don't have to worry about the subtype unsoundness propagating into the output.  For example, imagine that `updateTimestamp()` actually *set* the `timestamp` value of its input:

```
function updateTimestamp<T extends {
  timestamp: string & (string extends T["timestamp"] ? unknown : never)
}>(x: T) {
  (x as { timestamp: string }).timestamp = new Date().toDateString();
}
```

Then although the following would still be prevented:

```
// updateTimestamp(myBar); // this would be rejected
```

Nothing could possibly stop the following from happening:

```
const sneakyBar: { timestamp: string } = myBar; 
updateTimestamp(sneakyBar); // not rejected!
myBar.timestamp // "not today" at compile time, but string at runtime
```

You are allowed to assign a `Bar` value to a `{timestamp: string}` variable, and property writes are allowed.  That's just part of the language, and nothing you do with the `updateTimestamp()` function will change that.

As I said, you don't have this problem with your function because it does not mutate anything itself.  But just keep in mind that there are limits to the type safety of TypeScript and you are very close to one of them.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhAFiYBzCB5ArgC4xFIDeAsAFBJIBm+w8hAlgPbBL4wAmIhEACotIUQuBgAeQUggAPAcB5RySVqPFgYALiRiATi2xIAvgD4AFNVq05uwdaQBKXbjAtC0gDRIAROuhNGF8zJAAyVQCxCV0DIyxTckdafQhCfH1OMiQAOjy5Hyig3WAIAHckABF+CAsnHMI2aoEAZUJDbDrTAG5HE2pHQgBPGGQAIRB9JABeSJFAmKQAcmA2QjU2PiGlnoGaJHgOMSQwIYn9XXOZuY1FlbWNrZ2TXv3D4GPSsqvZ7j4BYS3LQWU7nJyvWgAegAVAcjusvuddAAFFjwADWknOPlKADcIPpQhFKPsbGp5tEtLF2vEIYloZDHO9jgAjS6Ta6IybdJCQyGyfT6Nj6ACEjj5SAAtKEAH7i-mCEbIJZxbA7FgqVbrEBQKAsLCgFkAG2QjTUSuWvi1jxAQ18Sxye1oJvWbHRtuu2SKi18Q0CBK2vl2+xhSBdSDdtt0JLJtG9VL0NOwdJMSAZjkjQ2ufxqgIWwMz4N5-Mze36VGooFEcEQSGRQrQLBZHgAksASOsY-RGMx2JwcwCKUFpLIFBAlCou3Gh4tVQkIhY56PFMokIIANr+GdaXwAXSQAH4uMB0asypwShB8fonH1LMkkHY144XGukqSkKl0plVHkcgVySBHQkC+KoajqBomhqNoOiwLoXj6J1zVGJAfhufNgPudZGieYMmXhE4zkmdkplmL1t0w60cNtZ46WZBFyjQgchAokEiJvHkJQJIVRXlKVJQEwShOEkShNlGUJLlEMFQtJYrQeai7XVTUHh1PUDRAY1TTYZDlTxAkHQsAAmABmAAWABWW8K32cNM09QCMN0X1-X0QNgyhWE7PdIZowfacgOpWCUzTRl9ns35eFzVjC04ksfLLaxK3AaAa2QABBI0BEyGoAFVgBYa8oGQElHAYJhWA4LgosHICR3kFdJwfeNgKXBclwa8dVw3LcgL3Q9j1PNhzyQS9r2s2hy1oSwn0EJx3zJCw5CQHV0MpVqkwSEx6hazlyjAgQIMaZoIBg+I6hTJDhhQtDyMC5YqM2Gi8LeAjQWI1COTIxz1t0LCbW2Dzi2q-4WKAtiwTitRGxUMo2HwI0eCQFlkFSAArCBmAgHgkPovRShAdF2OjH7ikTWDElmd79B5RxmLzdbFwJonIeB610cxgQeDFGzaGphoKOB+TsKeu0VvWQ4tBYE1HJ8FlSCXfhP0YAIyyAA)

Comment: Thanks for very exhaustive answer. I was afraid I'm hitting the edge here, but I wanted to be sure there is no straightforward way. Unfortunately my actual code is way more complicated, hits also other typescript bleeding edges and it will be a lot of pain to handle it reasonably without a "clean" solution, this was just an MWE of my problem, but I got some inspiration from your answer :)